# How to write a function which returns associative array and call the function in Oracle PLSQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

How to declare and define function which returns associative array in Oracle PL/SQL?
And how to call the same function from procedure ?

Comment: Define the associative array type in a package header, then reference the package.type name as your datatype. Or declare it locally as the other answers suggest. But this is pretty easy to gather from reading some online docs and tutorials.

Answer (score -1):

Declaration of package

```
CREATE or replace PACKAGE myinv AS 
                
           TYPE namevalue_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
           Procedure Test ( params IN varchar2 );
           Function ParseParams ( params IN varchar2) RETURN namevalue_type;
            
    END myinv ; 
    /
```

Definition of the package

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY myinv AS  
    --   TYPE namevalue_type IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(100) INDEX BY VARCHAR2(50);
    

       -- Function which does the parsing and returns associative array
       Function ParseParams ( params IN varchar2) 
       RETURN namevalue_type 
       IS
          nv_pairs SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
          nv_pair  SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
          i number;
          j number;
          name varchar2(100);
          value varchar2(100);
          nv_t namevalue_type;
    
       BEGIN 
       
             SELECT regexp_substr(params,'(.*?)(;|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
              BULK COLLECT INTO nv_pairs
              FROM   dual
              CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(params, ';') + 1;
            
              i := nv_pairs.FIRST;  -- Get first element of array
              while i is not null LOOP
                      
                  SELECT regexp_substr(nv_pairs(i),'(.*?)(=|$)', 1, level, NULL, 1)
                  BULK COLLECT INTO nv_pair
                  FROM   dual
                  CONNECT BY level <= regexp_count(nv_pairs(i), '=') + 1;
                  
                  j := nv_pair.FIRST;
                  while j is not null LOOP
                    name := nv_pair(j);
                    j := nv_pairs.NEXT(j); 
                    value := nv_pair(j);
                    nv_t(name) := value;
                    j := nv_pairs.NEXT(j); 
                  END LOOP;
                  
                 i := nv_pairs.NEXT(i);  -- Get next element of array      
              END LOOP;
              
              name := nv_t.FIRST;
              WHILE name IS NOT NULL LOOP
                name := nv_t.NEXT(name);
              END LOOP;
        
            RETURN nv_t;
    
       END ParseParams; 
       
       --Procedure to test the function
        Procedure Test ( params IN varchar2 )
        AS
        nvt namevalue_type;
        name varchar2(100);
        i number;
        BEGIN
        dbms_output.put_line('  Inside Procedure Test');
            i := 1;
            nvt := ParseParams('param1=10;param2=20');
            name := nvt.FIRST;
            WHILE name IS NOT NULL LOOP
              --dbms_output.put_line('            ' || i ||'. Name: ' || name || '  Value: ' || nvt(name) );
              dbms_output.put_line('            ' || i ||'. Name: ' || name || '  Value: ' || (to_number(nvt(name)) + 10) );
              name := nvt.NEXT(name);
              i := i+1;
            END LOOP;
              
              
        END Test;
    END myinv; 
    /
```

Run the test

```
    BEGIN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Test Parse.........................');
      myinv.Test('Check');
    END;
    /
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.